# The fastest way for archive node synchronization

Tags: node

I need a synced archive node.

I tried to reconstruct a full node snapshot, it takes 150 hours. 150 hours are too much.

Is there any faster way?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that is the fastest way. You *could* get a copy of someone else's archive node data, but this is discouraged by the Tezos core devs as certain seed data is stored within each archive node. Thus, with a copy of someone else's archive data, you would generate the same results as them which is bad for a decentralized network.

Comment: Retrieving someone else's node data is indeed discouraged. However, it is not related to some "stored seed data" (the node data is (mainly) canonical between nodes). The main reason is to avoid spreading a piece of data that may have been polluted.

Comment: @vect0r Pierre Boutillier, one of the lead devs, stated in baker's slack channel that it is indeed "stored seed data". Here's the link:  https://tezos-baking.slack.com/archives/CC4FD2HUY/p1575479535352100?thread_ts=1575443461.341300&cid=CC4FD2HUY

Comment: That's right, but the randomness he his referencing to is not implemented using a stored seed. The store is (mainly) canonical but it behaves differently on every node thanks to a "dynamic" randomness.